# When i try to run the command : sudo apt update,i get the following error :

Tags: docker, installation

When i try to run the command : `sudo apt update`, I get the following error :

```
error: E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation that the error message is referring you to?

Comment: (also, questions about apt are generally more topical on [UNIX.se] than here; it's a tool more used by system administrators than developers)

Comment: Quick search in Google: https://itslinuxfoss.com/fix-the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file